# Multi-threading not acting as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a C++ program that takes in a file input and counts the number of times a certain character occurs. Specifically, I wanted to use multi-threading to solve this problem to gain experience with multi-threading. However, I am receiving different results each execution and was wondering where I could be going wrong -- still learning C++. Any advice would be helpful.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

#define NUM_THREADS 5
const char flag = 'w';
int totalSum = 0;

bool matchesFlag(char letter) {
    return letter == flag;
}

void *processText(void *threadArg) {
    std::string text = *static_cast<std::string*>(threadArg);
    totalSum += std::count_if(text.begin(), text.end(), matchesFlag);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    inFile.open("text.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (inFile.good()) {
        getline(inFile, line);
        int created = -1;
        while (created) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS && created != 0; ++i) {
                created = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, processText, (void *)&line);    
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << totalSum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using std::thread?

Comment: I see at least four fundamental problems with the shown code. As designed, the shown code fails to properly synchronize multiple threads, not to mention what exactly is the reason behind starting four threads  whose purpose is to count the same letter in each line, thus expecting to get the final count that's four times as much, but due to lack of synchronization and atomicity, the end result will be completely random, not to mention that the `std::string` will go out of scope and get destroyed before any of these threads complete, resulting in undefined behavior, and a random crash.

Comment: Why are you creating 5 threads for every line of the file, which all repeat the same task for each line? What did you intend exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by I fail to properly synchronize multiple threads?

Comment: *Specifically, I wanted to use multi-threading to solve this problem to gain experience with multi-threading.* -- Advice -- make sure you read a *lot* of literature on this topic and understanding good sample programs before embarking on this.  Learning how to properly write MT programs shouldn't be done by trial and error.  MT programming involves much more than learning how to start threads.

Comment: *What do you mean by I fail to properly synchronize multiple threads?* -- Look at the `line` address you're passing and imagine what happens if one thread is paused while another takes over inside the thread function.

Comment: MT thread programming is an advanced topic that is easy to mess up.  If you are still learning C++, there be dragons here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, then let's look at the question and comments that have been written so far.

As proposed by stackoverflow, we should be nice the new members and follow the code of conduct.

Then we should try to help.

First the comments:

> Any reason why you are not using std::thread? – 2785528

Well, there could be many reasons. Maybe bopas2 is using c++98. Or maybe he is a linux low level enthusiast. Or maybe, bopas2 is rather new to C++ programming and wants to learn and understand. Anyway, it is just an example code.

My recomendation is: If a C++ 11 (or later) compiler is available, then you should use this and you should start to learn the new C++ threading features.

Next comment

> I see at least four fundamental problems with the shown code. As designed, the shown code fails to properly synchronize multiple threads, not to mention what exactly is the reason behind starting four threads whose purpose is to count the same letter in each line, thus expecting to get the final count that's four times as much, but due to lack of synchronization and atomicity, the end result will be completely random, not to mention that the std::string will go out of scope and get destroyed before any of these threads complete, resulting in undefined behavior, and a random crash. – Sam Varshavchik

Yes, indeed there are problems in this code. But, if you look at the code, only one thread per line will be started. It will be tried 5 times, as long as it fails and pthread_create returns -1. If pthread_create succeeds, it will return 0 and the loop will be terminated. Most probably, the pthread_create will succeed always, having the thread handle always overwritten and in the array position 0 of threads. Overwriting is not good, but will not harm for this example. Becuase the result of pthread_create will not be used later. As to my understanding there is no need to synchronize the tasks (for example with join or whatever): Also the atomicity is not an issue. The std::string is not a problem, when it goes out of scope. There is a local copy (a threadlocal variable) of the std::string line. There will never be a random crash because of the above.

Next comment

> Why are you creating 5 threads for every line of the file, which all repeat the same task for each line? What did you intend exactly?

That is a wrong statement. Only one thread is started per read line. If there are multi lines, also multiple threads are/could-be started. However. I would not recommend to use such an error handling/recovery strategy.

Last comment

> Advice -- make sure you read a lot of literature on this topic and understanding good sample programs before embarking on this. Learning how to properly write MT programs shouldn't be done by trial and error. MT programming involves much more than learning how to start threads

That's very true. Multitasking is most complex and needs a lot of reading, practice and long years of understanding. Most people, who think they are understanding Multi Threading, simply do not. Me neither.

But everybody needs to start . . .

My analysis and answer to the question is (and I am not sure):

The start of the thread function and with that the local copy of the thread function parameter threadArg, could be later than reading the next line. That means, the variable could be copied after the next line has been read already. And since a pointer is used, this could have an impact. So, in one test, a line could be interpreted correctly and in the next run it could be read late. This will lead to different results.

Second problem is "totalSum += ". Here we do a read (no Problem) and a write. There could be a so called race condition. 2 threads trying to access the same global variable. And then a tread change during the assignment, where an old vaiable could be used twice. But here I am not sure and people, more expert than me, need to judge.

But the general rule is: If you write to a global variable like in your example totalSum, protect a thread change during this operation. There are different methods available. Most common is the usage of a mutex (I cannot go in too much detail on all of this here) or a critical section or locks or conditional variables or std::atomic or whatever your operating system is offering.

Important is that you prevent even the possibility that a variable will be written twice. Global variables should be avoided in most cases.

Maybe reading [this](https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-cplusplus-multithreading-mistakes/) will give you a little bit more insight.

I hope I could help at least a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the thought out answer -- I appreciate it. After posting this, I started reading "C++ concurrency in action" because I do need to learn more and do less guesswork. Thank you for noticing the other break point in the for loop, however, I feel like this "checking" to see if a thread has completed and to start analyzing a next line seems inefficient -- is there a better way to see if a thread has completed?

I see the problem with the global variable, was going to use promises/futures possibly, but mutexes may also be the answer.